# How to use before_filter inside a core modification in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I've created a plugin on redmine which modifies the core of RepositoryControler.

I've added a patch with new function inside this controller and I can call this function based on role permissions.

But to set up correctly the permissions I need to configure `before_filter` with authorization (`:authorize`) for my new function.

The trouble is because adding the before_filter inside my patch doesn't work and I don't know what is the best manner to do it. Following my code:

client.rb

```
module RepositoriesPatch
    require_dependency 'repositories_controller'

    def self.included(base)
      base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
    end
end

module InstanceMethods

  require_dependency 'repositories_controller'

  #I THINK THE BEFORE_FILTER SHOULD BE PLACED HERE, BUT IT DIDN'T WORKED.
  # before_filter :authorize, :only => :exec_client   (????????)

   def exec_client
    begin
     ....
    end

end

Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  RepositoriesController.send(:include, RepositoriesPatch)
end
```

init.rb

```
  permission :repositories, :repositories => :exec_client

  project_module :repository do
    permission :exec, :repository => :exec_client
  end

  Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
    RepositoriesController.send(:include, RepositoriesPatch)
  end

  settings :default => {'empty' => true}, :partial => 'settings/gerar_versao_configuration'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`before_filter` must be evaluated inside the class as follows:

```
def self.included(base)
    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
    base.class_eval do
        unloadable
        before_filter :authorize, :only => :exec_client
    end
end
```

Comment: Works perfectly and smoothly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as an aside in Rails 4 introduced "before_action" which apparently over time will replace "before_filter"

Pierre